# Caliburn.micro DataGridComboBoxColumn not binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I have read a lot of articles before to ask the question, but finally I decided to write here because I wasn't able to find one that can fit in my solution.

I have the following `DataGrid` on a View:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="UsersCollection" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="525" Width="510" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="147" Canvas.Top="26" Margin="0">
         <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="Languages" />
         </DataGrid.Columns>
```

And this is part of my ViewModel:

```
 private List<string> _languages;



    [ImportingConstructor]
    public UsersViewModel()
    {
        DisplayName = "Users";
        _usersCollection = new TrulyObservableCollection<UserModel>();
        foreach (UserModel user in GetAllUsers())
            _usersCollection.Add(user);

        _usersCollection.CollectionChanged += Users_CollectionChanged;
        _usersCollection.ItemPropertyChanged += PropertyChangedHandler;

        _languages = new List<string>();
        _languages.Add("es");
        _languages.Add("ca");
        _languages.Add("en");
    }

    public List<string> Languages
    {
        get { return _languages; }
    }
```

My UserModel have this Property:

```
    public string Language
    {
        get { return _language; }
        set
        {
            if (_language != value)
            {
                _language = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Language);
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I do it to bind the `DataGrid` combo (of course, related with the Language property of the UserModel) ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is somewhat confusing, if i understand you correctly, you want to bind `SelectedItem` to the `Language` property, and `ItemsSource` to `Languages`.

Comment: Ok sorry, I will try to do it better: I am binding a collection of UserModels into a DataGrid. One of the properties of each UserModel is Language. I want to can change the cell of the column where is binded the property "Language" with a combobox with different values. After that, the INPC will fire the change.

Comment: Yes, I noted it after post it, although it still does not work, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to run something:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="UsersCollection" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="525" Width="510" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="147" Canvas.Top="26" Margin="0">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="*">
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.Languages}"/>
                <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding Language}" />
            </Style>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.Languages}"/>
                <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding Language}" />
            </Style>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Actually works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following, in your view:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="UsersCollection" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="525" Width="510" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="147" Canvas.Top="26" Margin="0">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource={Binding ElementName=UsersCollection, Path=DataContext.Languages} SelectedItemBinding={Binding Path=Language} />
     </DataGrid.Columns>
```

If the view in which you have the `DataGrid` inside has a name, like for example if your `DataGrid` is inside a `UserControl` that has a name `myUserControl`, then try the following small modification:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource={Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=DataContext.Languages} SelectedItemBinding={Binding Path=Language} />
     </DataGrid.Columns>
```

If the view containing the `DataGrid` doesn't have a name, just give it one and use the above code.

Comment: Thank you Sniffer, but it doesn't work. This issue is driving me crazy!

Comment: @OscarMateu Can you tell me what you can see in the output window when you run the application in debug mode.

Comment: @OscarMateu I have edited my answer a bit, please check the edit. I have to go for now. If you have any questions or comments just leave them and I will respond later when I can.

Comment: This error is showed in the output:

System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.Languages; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridComboBoxColumn' (HashCode=45180734); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Comment: <UserControl x:Class="TOP.TabUsersView"
             x:Name="TabUsersUC" (...)

<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=TabUsersUC, Path=DataContext.Languages}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=Language}" />

Comment: Thank you so much Stefan. I keep working on it, the Languages collection is never called. There should be another way to bind this column combo!

Comment: Please, see my edit to the question. I almost solved the problem but it still does not work perfectly.

Comment: @OscarMateu Didn't the latter syntax work correctly, i mean when you gave a name to the UserControl ?

Comment: @OscarMateu In your last edit, try to use `SelectedItemBinding` instead of `SelectedItem` and see how it goes.